# How to set delegate type UITextField.ShouldReturn asynchronously?

Tags: c#, delegates, lambda, xamarin.ios, async-await

I am trying to make a call to my webservice from iOS device when user presses GO on touch keyboard. I want a loading indicator to be shown while it talks to the webservice.

I am using lambda expression for delegate type UITextFieldCondition.

```cs
    LoginField.ShouldReturn = async textField => { 
        await LoginAsync();
        return textField.ResignFirstResponder();
    };
```

The compiler shows me the following error:

> Cannot convert async lambda expression to delegate type `MonoTouch.UIKit.UITextFieldCondition'

The code works if I do it synchronously:

```cs
    LoginField.ShouldReturn = textField => { 
        Login();
        return textField.ResignFirstResponder();
    };
```

Is there a way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, there is no way to do that. The signature of `UITextFieldCondition` means that your delegate has to *synchronously* return the result.

I think you need to change the way you handle this. Maybe something like:

```
LoginField.ShouldReturn = textField =>
{ 
    LoginAsync().ContinueWith(t => /* react to t.Result manually here */);
    return false;
};
```